# Как вставить сгенерированное значение идентификатора в два поля

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, oracle-adf

Существует legacy проект в котором есть следующие таблицы

Master(masterId (pk), detailId (not null), createDate (not null))

Detail (detailId (not null), field1, field2) - составной pk (detailId, field1, field2)

Собственно старый adf (привожу псевдокод) код делал следующее:

```
MasterRow m = createMasterRow;
Long masterId = m.masterId;
m.detailId = masterId;
m.createDate = new Date();//без времени
Set<DetailRowIter> details = m.detailRowIter;
for (InerDetail d: dList)
{
  DetailRow det = createDetailRow;
  det.detailId = masterId;
  det.one = d.one;
  det.two = d.two;
  det.insertRow()
}
commit();
```

Можете объяснить как работает adf в данном случае? Почему вот тут

```
MasterRow m = createMasterRow;
```

уже есть идешник, но при этом не идет вставка сразу как вызвали commit (т.е. в старом коде работает все нормально). А если переписать на Hibernate

```
...
m = new Master(); 
m.persiste(); 
master.detailId = master.masterId; 
...
```

то после завершения транзакции выводится сообщение об ошибке: не возможно вставить null в поле detailId

Код hibernate (panache) привожу ниже

```
@Entity
@RegisterForReflection
@Table(name = "Master")
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
public class Master extends PanacheEntityBase {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "MASTER_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "MASTER_SEQ", sequenceName = "MASTER_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "MASTERID", nullable = false)
    Long masterId;

    @Column(name = "DETAILID", nullable = false)
    Long detailId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "master", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    Set<BatchContent> details = new HashSet<>(0);

    @Column(name = "CREATEDATE", nullable = false)
    Date createDate;

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
       createDate = clearTime(Calendar.getInstance()).getTime();
    }

    private Calendar clearTime(Calendar cal) {
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        return cal;
    }
}
```

Сущность Detail

```
@Entity
@RegisterForReflection
@IdClass(Detail.DetailId.class)
@Table(name = "Detail")
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
public class Detail extends PanacheEntityBase {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinColumn(name = "DETAILID", nullable = false)
    Master master;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "FIELD1")
    Long field1;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "FIELD2")
    Long field2;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @RegisterForReflection
    @FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    static class DetailId implements Serializable {

        Master master;

        Long field1;

        Long field2;

    }

}
```

Тестовый код для создание нового мастера

```
    Master master = new Master();
    // master.persist();
    // master.detailId = master.masterId;
    Detail detail = new Detail();
    content.field1 = 1L;
    content.field2 = 2L;
    content.batch = batch;
    master.details.add(content);

    master.persist();
    detail = new Detail();
    content.field1 = 2L;
    content.field2 = 3L;
    content.batch = batch;
    master.details.add(content);
    return master.masterId;
```

И получается что вставка не возможна по причине того что detailId в master'е не может быть пуст. Подскажите, каким образом можно описать такую сущность с помощью хибернейта (возможно указав чтобы при вставке master'а один сгенерированный ключ использовался бы для двух полей). Либо же надо писать нативный запрос для получения идентификатора из сиквенса, убрав его из сущности GeneratedValue и расставлять самостоятельно при создании?

Comment: Попробуйте в PrePersist написать detailId = masterId. Ещё можно попробовать и для detailId указать GeneratedValue или на сущность положено иметь не более одного GeneratedValue?

Comment: @Sergey добрый день. Увы но PrePersist еще не имеет сгенерированного идешника. А GeneratedValue нельзя ставить более чем на два поля, как я понял, покопавшись в интернете и документации

Comment: Надо сделать view с нормальными связями. И мапить эти вьюхи. При сохранении тригерами пдгонять под исходные таблицы.

Comment: @Segey все же мне не хотелось каким либо образом изменять базу данных. При реализации данной задачи все же надо воспринимать базу данных как что-то к чему у вас доступ только на чтение/запись в таблицы и никаких изменений схемы :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пришел в итоге к выводу что, то что я хочу сделать невозможно в рамках описания сущностей хибернейта. Дело не в очень хорошей архитектуре базы данных. Но если у кого-то есть подобная проблема, то вот такое решение (возможно не самое оптимально, рабочее):

Master.java

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@RegisterForReflection
@Table(name = "MASTER")
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
public class Master extends PanacheEntityBase {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "MASTERID", nullable = false)
    Long masterId;

    @Column(name = "DETAILID", nullable = false)
    Long detailId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "master", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    Set<Detail> details = new HashSet<>(0);

    @Column(name = "DATECREATED", nullable = false)
    Date dateCreated;

    public static Master createMasterWithLoadId() {
        Query nativeQuery = Panache.getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("select MASTER_SEQ.nextval from dual");
        Master master = new Master();
        master.masterId = id;
        master.detailId = id;
        return master;
    }

     @PrePersist
     public void prePersist() {
        if (dateCreated == null) {
           dateCreated = clearTime(Calendar.getInstance()).getTime();
        }
     }

     private Calendar clearTime(Calendar cal) {
         cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
         cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
         cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
         cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
         return cal;
     }
}
```

Detail.java

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@RegisterForReflection
@IdClass(BatchContent.ContentId.class)
@Table(name = "DETAIL")
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
public class Detail extends PanacheEntityBase {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinColumn(name = "detailId", nullable = false)
    Master master;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "one")
    Long one;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "two")
    Long two;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @RegisterForReflection
    @FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    static class DetailId implements Serializable {

        Master master;

        Long one;

        Long two;

    }
}
```

Использование:

```
Master master = Master.createMasterWithLoadId();
for (RequestDetail rDet : rDetails) {
    master.details.add(new Detail(master, rDet.getOne(), rDet.getTwo()));
}
master.persist();
```

Comment: Eager и Set<> лучше не использовать